# Model validation using features (R)

Tags: r, validation, caret

I'm trying to create a classification model in R, at the moment i'm using 10 fold CV (using the train function of caret package)

```
trainControl(method='cv',number=10)
```

What i would like to do is split the data using a feature in the data.

for example, if i have a feature that contains the values: {green, black, red},
i would like to validate using 3 models each will learn using only 2 of the values, and will be validated using the other one. This feature (the colors) should **not** be part of the instance while training the model...

Is it possible to do this using the train function in caret, or in any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with `caret` but would need to define your own resampling indices. Here is an example using the iris data:

```
groups <- levels(iris$Species)
for_model <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(groups))
names(for_model) <- groups

for(i in seq(along = groups)) 
  for_model[[i]] <- which(iris$Species != groups[i])


mod <- train(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, data = iris,
             method = "lm",
             trControl = trainControl(method = "cv",
                                      index = for_model))
```

and some output:

```
> str(for_model)
List of 3
 $ setosa    : int [1:100] 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 ...
 $ versicolor: int [1:100] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ virginica : int [1:100] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
> mod$resample
       RMSE  Rsquared   Resample
1 0.9568618 0.5513756     setosa
2 0.5379393 0.2765821 versicolor
3 0.3764072 0.2090573  virginica
```